# C# updating MSAccess data

Tags: c#, ms-access

I'm loading two fields, one from a combo box and the other is a text field.
I want to update the text field with the selection from the combo box.
The display changes, but it's not writing out to the DB.  Any help would be appreciated. - THANKS!!!!!!

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'scrumMasterDataSet.Current_Configuration_Settings' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.current_Configuration_SettingsTableAdapter.Fill(this.scrumMasterDataSet.Current_Configuration_Settings);
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'scrumMasterDataSet.Teams' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.teamsTableAdapter.Fill(this.scrumMasterDataSet.Teams);

    }

    private void team_NamesComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String status = team_NamesComboBox.Text;
        team_NameTextBox.Text = status;
    }

    private void team_NameTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //this.teamsTableAdapter.Update(this.scrumMasterDataSet.Teams);
        this.Validate();
        this.current_Configuration_SettingsBindingSource.EndEdit();
        this.current_Configuration_SettingsTableAdapter.Update(this.scrumMasterDataSet.Current_Configuration_Settings);
    }
}
```

}

EDIT:

I'm trying to update the "Current_Configuration_Settings" table with the value the user selects from the "Teams" table.

The "Current_Configuration_Settings" table has 4 fields 'ID', 'Team Name', 'User' and 'Role'

The "Teams" table has two fields 'ID' and 'Team Names'

I have a combo box to select the team name and I copy that over to the 'Team Name' text box that's bound to the Current_Configuration_Settings table.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't actually changing any value in the data table before you call update.

If you're trying to set "Team Name" in the config settings, and assuming the config settings are in row 0, try:

```
this.scrumMasterDataSet.Current_Configuration_Settings[0]["Team Name"] = team_NameTextBox.Text;
this.current_Configuration_SettingsTableAdapter.Update(this.scrumMasterDataSet.Current_Configuration_Settings);
```

Comment: I changed this line:

this.scrumMasterDataSet.Teams["Name"] = team_NameTextBox.Text;

to this:
this.scrumMasterDataSet.Current_Configuration_Settings["Team Name"] = team_NamesComboBox.Text;

However it won't compile and seems to want and integer where the field name is.

The error is - Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'int'

If i change it ["Team Name"] to [1] it says it's read only

Comment: It sounds like you changed which table you're working with, from "Teams" to "Current_Configuration_Settings" in that comment. Which table are you trying to change values in? It may help to put a short description of your scrumMasterDataSet's schema (or at least the fields involved from each table and their type) at the bottom of your question to help us get a better idea of what you're working with.

Comment: So, I'm trying to update the "Current_Configuration_Settings" table with the value the user selects from the "Teams" table.

Comment: The "Current_Configuration_Settings" table has 4 fields 'ID', 'Team Name', 'User' and 'Role'

Comment: The "Teams" table has two fields 'ID' and role

Comment: Sorry 'ID' and 'Team Names'

Comment: I have a combo box to select the team name and I copy that over to the 'Team Name' text box that's bound to the Current_Configuration_Settings table

Comment: My syntax was wrong. table["Value"] is nonsense. It should be table[rowNumber]["Value"], so Configuration_Settings[0]["Team Name"].